# Android - error opening file just created

Tags: java, android, file, file-io, io

I'm new to android developement and trying to do some file IO. Whenever I run this block of code:

```
File meta = new File(context.getAppContext().getFilesDir(),"meta");
meta.mkdirs();
File dir = new File(meta,"subdir");
File imageFile = new File(dir,"filename");
Log.d("test",imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
```

I get this error:

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.android.networkusage/files/meta/Greg and The Morning Buzz/artwork30.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
    at com.example.android.networkusage.Podcast.downloadArtworkFromUrl(Podcast.java:117)
    at com.example.android.networkusage.Podcast.<init>(Podcast.java:93)
    at com.example.android.networkusage.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:113)
    at com.example.android.networkusage.NetworkActivity.loadXmlFromNetwork(NetworkActivity.java:240)
    at com.example.android.networkusage.NetworkActivity.access$100(NetworkActivity.java:65)
    at com.example.android.networkusage.NetworkActivity$DownloadXmlTask.doInBackground(NetworkActivity.java:203)
    at com.example.android.networkusage.NetworkActivity$DownloadXmlTask.doInBackground(NetworkActivity.java:198)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
    ... 16 more
```

The log even prints out the file's path as directed, so the file must exist! Why is this happening?

Also, my app has internal and external write priviledges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the sub-directories (`subdir`) and file do not exist.  The code should call `createNewFile()` to actually create the file.  Also the `subdir` directory needs to be made by calling `mkdirs()`.

```
File meta = new File(context.getAppContext().getFilesDir(),"meta")
meta.mkdirs();
File dir = new File(meta, "subdir");
dir.mkdirs(); //added
File imageFile = new File(dir, "filename.txt");
imageFile.createNewFile(); //added
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
```

I do not believe the `File` constructor actually creates the file on the file system.  The documentation states:

> Instances of this class may or may not denote an actual file-system
>   object such as a file or a directory. If it does denote such an object
>   then that object resides in a partition. A partition is an operating
>   system-specific portion of storage for a file system. A single storage
>   device (e.g. a physical disk-drive, flash memory, CD-ROM) may contain
>   multiple partitions. The object, if any, will reside on the partition
>   named by some ancestor of the absolute form of this pathname.

Comment: @anonymouse Any luck?

Comment: Hi Kevin, sorry I took so long to reply. Your answer worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this is a snippet of code from a project i'm working on right now :

from inside an activity/context :

```
File dir = getDir("Foler", 0);        // i think your problem is here
File file = new File(dir,"File.bin");
```

creating directory in android is different than java on normal computer, try to create your directory using getDir() instead of new File(...).mkdirs(), and make sure it is from inside a context (after the activity is created)

i dont believe i'm the best one to answer this question since i'm new to android as well, but maybe this helps

so final code maybe like this

```
File dir = getDir("subdir",0);
File imageFile = new File(dir, "filename.txt");
imageFile.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
```

i dont know about making nested directories, i didnt try it up till now